# Storing templated objects in a vector (Storing Class<int>, Class<double> in a single vector)

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, stdvector

There is a templated class, let it be

```
template<typename T> class A { std::vector<T> data; };
```

The problem I am facing here is, users can create several types of this class, but I need to track them, best case is I have a reference of these objects in another vector, but that would not work since all types are different.
Can you recommend a good design pattern which can encapsulate this.

I can store pointers and then typecast it, but its not elegant.

I can change the architecture as well, if the solution provided is good enough. 
The basic question I am trying to solve is, I have a class of vector of custom types, how do I store them.

Comment: Why do you need to store them in a single container? Can you give an example on  how this vector of references would be used?

Comment: Are the types represented by T related in some way? i.e. common interface or common base class?

Answer (score 1):

As previous comments stated - you first need to make sure this is what you need.

With that been said, I had a similar requirement in a project of mine, which I eventually solved with inheritance and PIMPL, as follows:

```
class A{
private:
    struct Abstract {
        virtual void f() = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Implementation : public Abstract {
        std::vector<T> data;
        virtual void f() {...}
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Abstract> impl;

public:
    template <typename T>
    A(): impl(std::make_unique<Implementation<T> >()){}

    void f() {impl->f();}
};
```

This allows you to create a container of objects of type `A`, and access them via the public interface defined therein (the method `f`). The underlying type `T` of each `A` object is specified on construction. All other implementation details specific to the type `T` are hidden.

The solution suffers the inherent overhead of virtual functions. I'm not sure how it compares to the std::any approach performance-wise.

Comment: std::any internally uses virtual functions/inheritance. The performance will approximately be the same. The previous solution I showed was for `std::variant` which does not use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

`std::any` is the modern c++17 solution. Specifically, you should use

```
A<int> a;
a.data.push_back(0);

// fill refernces...
std::vector<std::any> refernces; 
refernces.push_back(&a.data[0]);

// check which type is active.
if(int** iPtr = std::any_cast<int*>(&references[0]); iPtr != nullptr)
{
     // its an int*
     int& i = **iPtr;
     // do something with i.
}
```

These pointers can point into the `A<int>::data` and `A<double>::data` vectors.

For a complete reference, see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any.

Comment: I am using modern c++ but, this was an example. There can be infinite number of examples, like custom classes etc. 
Example: A<AnyClass> var;

Comment: You can use `std::any`. But you should really think hard about whether this is a good design overall. Do you really need to allow any type there?

Also, if `A<T>::data` reallocates/resizes, all these pointers will be invalidated. You might want a better overall structure.

Comment: std::any, followed by a cast on extraction, seems kind of unsafe. But yes, the constraint stands, there are too many different objects to keep track of. BTW i have updated the question, You can recommend me a good design for this problem, I can refactor my code.