# Templated Base Class yet have a common base class pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, type-erasure

I am trying to build an execution graph where each node can produce multiple outputs of different types and consume multiple inputs of different types. Data is transferred between the nodes via queues.

To connect 2 nodes, the input type of one node must be connected to the same output type of the other node. For example, trying to connect the `int` output of one node to the `double` input of another node should yield in a compilation error.

All nodes will derive from a base class that has a `execute()` method that reads from the different input types and writes into the different output types. Currently, I have something like this-

```
struct Node {
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

struct IntegerGeneratorNode: public Node {
    void execute() {
        while(some_condition_is_not_met) {
           // write() will do std::queue<int>::push();
           int_out.write(some_rand_integer);
        }
    }
    Output<int> int_out;
};

struct FloatGeneratorNode: public Node {
    void execute() {
        while(some_condition_is_not_met) {
           // write() will do std::queue<float>::push();
           float_out.write(some_rand_float);
        }
    }
    Output<float> float_out;
};

struct SinkNode: public Node {
    void execute() {
        while(some_condition) {
           int val = int_inp.read(); // invokes queue<int>::front()+pop()
           float f_val = float_inp.read();
           // Do something with val and f_val.
        }
    }
    Input<int> int_inp;
    Input<float> float_inp;
};
```

`Input<T>` is a templated class that has a `queue` of type `T`. `Output<T>` is a templated class that has a pointer to a `queue` of type `T`. To connect 2 nodes, I do something like-

```
Node *int_node = IntegerGeneratorNode();
Node *float_node = FloatGeneratorNode();
Node *sink_node = SinkNode();

int_node.int_out.connect(sink_node.int_inp);
float_node.float_out.connect(sink_node.float_inpt);

std::thread int_thread([](Node *node){ node->execute(); }, int_node);
std::thread float_thread([](Node *node){ node->execute(); }, float_node);
std::thread sink_thread([](Node *node){ node->execute(); }, sink_node);
```

This works fine but I have another requirement- perform some operation on ALL the `Input<T>`s of a `Node` before the `execute` method is called - `Input<T>::doSomePreProcessing()`. As you can see, having named variables doesn't scale. You have to add a `.doSomething` on ALL the variables you have. I need some kind of looping.

One idea is to have a `tuple` of `Input` types and iterate the tuple using C++17 `std::apply`. But another major requirement I have is that the derived classes are client code and base class is framework code. All preprocessing must be done from the base class to lessen the burden the load on the derived classes. To do this I need to move the tuple to the base class like this-

```
template<typename T>
struct Node {
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    void doExecute {
        preprocess(some_tuple);
        execute();
    }
    T inputs() { return input_tuple; }
    T input_tuple;
};

template<typename T>
struct SinkNode: public Node<T>{
   ...
};

// Call site.
SinkNode<std::tuple<int,float>> sink_node;
```

2 side-effects happened cos of this change

1. The base class is now templated and I can no longer have a common base class pointer which is required to invoke `doExecute` method on the nodes of the graph.
2. `connect` is hard to implement. Ideally what I am looking for is

```
template<typename T>
void connect(Node* src, Node* dest) {
    std::get<T>(src.outputs()).connect(std::get<T>(dest.inputs()));
}
```

But since `Node*` is not available anymore, I can't do this.

How do I do all processing on the inputs in the base class yet have a common base class pointer? In other words not have it templated?

Comment: I'm not clear on your example. Firstly, it's unclear how the queues are used actually, even a dummy operation would be enough. Then, you never call `execute()` in the example either. Lastly, you want to avoid having to write code, but could you write it down nonetheless as example? I have a feeling that the so-called Template Method Pattern (unrelated to C++ templates) might be a promising approach for you, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can't you simply keep a container of all `SinkNode` objects (or a container of pointers to `SinkNode` objects)?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I added more details

Comment: Node can be implemented without a template. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454874/storing-templated-objects-in-a-vector-storing-classint-classdouble-in-a-si/54456975#54456975

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches come to mind:

1. Split off the `virtual void execute() = 0` into a separate baseclass, from which you then derive the different, templated baseclasses.
2. Apply the Decorator Pattern: Just create a `Node` class that wraps another `Node` class. When the outer `execute()` is called, preprocess the input and then invoke the inner `execute()`.
3. Use multiple inheritance. One base class might provide the `execute()` interface, another might provide the preprocessing interface. This is similar to the first variant, only that the two parts are not stacked on top of each other but rather next to each other on the same level.