# C++ Higher order templates

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a system in C++ where I can implement many different entities E each with a different type T associated to them. I want to make a generic owner for these so that for implementations E1 associated to T1, E2 associated to T2 ect, I can wrap them inside a container where they can all be managed, something like (in pseudocode)

```
E<ConcreteT1> e1;
E<ConcreteT2> e2;
//...
Container c;
c.add(e1)
c.add(e2)
//...
```

I'm a beginner in C++ and I'm aware of basic templates, but I think I need some kind of 'higher order template' where the top level (C) is generic over the middle level (E) which is in turn generic over subsequent levels. Maybe this is a total anti-pattern and I'm doing something completely wrong. Please let me know how to solve this problem. I'm happy to use C++17 features but I would rather avoid the latest and greatest C++20 if possible.

Thank you

EDIT:
The actual problem I'm trying to solve is to have an interface taking a generic E (event) in some of the methods.

```
template <typename E>
class Interface{
  method(E e){...}
}
```

I want to implement many concretions (event handlers) each with their own E (kind of events)

```
class EOne{}
class ImplOne:Interface<EOne>{
  method(Eone e){...}
}

class ETwo{}
class ImplTwo:Interface<ETwo>{
  method(ETwo e){...}
}
```

and then manage these in some more containers, say `Container c` as above. Then I will have a queue of callables where the callables may call methodN with the respective event types.

```
for(auto &handler:container){
 eventQueue.pop()();
}
```

I know I'm probably going down the wrong road here.

Comment: The question seems to broad or needs more details (it's not really clear what problem are you trying solve ??). Are you trying to avoid inheritance ? would a variant be helpfull https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant ?

Comment: To my knowledge STL does not support what is called a heterogeneous container, that is, a container that stores multiple types of input in your case ConreteT1 and ConcreteT2. What does the container you want look like?

Comment: Theres also the std::any type - basic form of type erasure

Comment: the question is unclear, but you may want to take a look at template template parameters, but chances are high that you are just overthinking something that actually isnt that difficult. You know that `some_template<T>` is just a type like any other and it doesnt really matter that it comes from isntantiating a template?

Comment: About my previous comment, apparently STL has adopted boost's "any" as mentioned by @darune

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it is hard to explain my problem with my limited C++. I have added an edit to try and summarise my actual problem as succinctly as I can. I don't want to use any as I think having to use that means something in my design is really wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing templated objects in a vector (Storing Class<int>, Class<double> in a single vector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454874/storing-templated-objects-in-a-vector-storing-classint-classdouble-in-a-si)

Comment: That's a great suggestion but I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: The closest way I can think of is to have the template E to always instantiate to a class that inherits from a base class, and have the container hold elements of that base class. If you don't want to expose that base class, you can have Container be an alias to such a container.

Comment: @Dan what about std::variant then ? (or inheritance perhaps)

Comment: @darune it seems like the best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `std::variant` and use visitation.

Eg. the queue object could be defined as

```
using InterfaceVar = std::variant<Interface<E1>, Interface<E2>>;
std::queue< InterfaceVar > eventQueue;
```

Then you would use visitation to discriminate on the type (It sounds like you want it this way). You could use `std::visit` for this or your own method of visitation.

[Example from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
 
// the variant to visit
using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>;
 
// helper constant for the visitor #3
template<class> inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;
 
// helper type for the visitor #4
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
 
int main() {
    std::vector<var_t> vec = {10, 15l, 1.5, "hello"};
    for(auto& v: vec) {
 
        // 1. void visitor, only called for side-effects (here, for I/O)
        std::visit([](auto&& arg){std::cout << arg;}, v);
 
        // 2. value-returning visitor, demonstrates the idiom of returning another variant
        var_t w = std::visit([](auto&& arg) -> var_t {return arg + arg;}, v);
 
        // 3. type-matching visitor: a lambda that handles each type differently
        std::cout << ". After doubling, variant holds ";
        std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
            using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
                std::cout << "int with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)
                std::cout << "long with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
                std::cout << "double with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
                std::cout << "std::string with value " << std::quoted(arg) << '\n';
            else 
                static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
        }, w);
    }
 
    for (auto& v: vec) {
        // 4. another type-matching visitor: a class with 3 overloaded operator()'s
        std::visit(overloaded {
            [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
            [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
            [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; },
        }, v);
    }
}
```